# displaying an array with previous values in a list

Tags: php, arrays, list, foreach

I have an array in php that looks like:

`array(1 => 'Toyota', 2 => 'Corolla', 3 => '1997', 4 => '1.5L', 5 => 'Engine Parts');`

how do I make it print out like:

Toyota

Toyota,Corolla

Toyota,Corolla,1997

Toyota,Corolla,1997,1.5L

Toyota,Corolla,1997,1.5L,Engine Parts

I did it before accidentally using foreach but can't figure out how I did it.

Comment: lol at you did it before accidentally :D +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$parts = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    $parts[] = $value;
    echo implode(",", $parts);
}
```

Comment: you may want to add a space after ,

Comment: @JaspreetChahal There wasn't one in the asker's question, so I didn't put one in.

Comment: Yep that was it implode. Perfect.